# UITapGestureRecognizer for Single and Double Tap

Tags: swift

I want to create two gestures for my app. Single tap and double tap. Each gesture represent different action that I am going to take. I have the following code but it only fires a single tap:

```
 private func registerGestureRecognizers() {

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1


        let doubleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
        doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
    }
```

Comment: There is a Swift 3 answer in the duplicate.

Comment: Where?? can you provide a link? or something

Comment: I did provide a link - see the top of your question. Scroll down through the answers for the one clearly labeled as Swift 3.

Comment: I am lost. I don't see any link at all. Okay found it finally

Comment: Reload this page. The link is above your question.